# SKCameraNode doesn't keep up with moving node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am currently trying to make a "launch(er) game", i.e. a game in the style of Toss the turle, Learn to fly and Burrito Bison using SpriteKit. I've gotten the launch to work using the built-in physics of SpriteKit, but when I try to use an SKCameraNode to follow the main character, it seems like it's always one (or more) step behind which makes the main character "shake" at high velocities.

I've tried both setting the position of the camera using SKAction and with the .position-property, with the same result.

I guess this is because the update of the physics are done at a faster rate than the actual update(), and I've tried searching for information about this but found zilch.

Function for "launching" the main character:

```
func touchStopped(touchPoint: CGPoint) {
    if !inAir {
        arrow.removeFromParent()
        inAir = true

        mainCharNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: mainCharNode.size.width/2)
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.mass = mainChar.mass
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.restitution = mainChar.restitution
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = mainChar.airResistance
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(touchPoint.x*2, touchPoint.y)
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = mainCategory
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = groundCategory
    } else {
        mainCharNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10000, 10000))
    }
}
```

Update()-function:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime

    if mainCharNode.position.x > 1000 {
        let moveCamera = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: mainCharNode.position.x, y: cameraNode.position.y), duration: dt)
        cameraNode.runAction(moveCamera)
    }
    if(inAir && !gameOver) {
        distance += (mainCharNode.physicsBody?.velocity.dx)!*CGFloat(dt)
        if(mainCharNode.physicsBody?.velocity == CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)) {
             gameOver = true
             mainCharNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/CalleLundstedt/LauncherGame here is the full project on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By manually setting the camera position in `update`, you're delaying the camera movement by at least one frame — physics runs after `update`, so your camera move happens on the frame after your character moves.

When you use a move action instead of directly setting the position, and giving that action a nonzero duration, you're delaying the camera move even more. (The `dt` in your code is the time between this frame and the last one before it, and you're applying that time to a *future* movement.) Because the character is still moving while your action runs, the camera will never catch up — you're always moving the camera to where the character *was*.

Setting the camera position at all is just making extra work for yourself, though. Use [`SKConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html) instead, and SpriteKit itself will make sure that the camera position sticks to the character — it solves constraints after physics, but on the same frame.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works perfectly!
The problem now is to make sure that the y-value of the camera node is constant as long as the main character is inside the screen, (i.e. if mainCharNode.position.y < topOfScreen).

Comment: Right now I have two constraints, a distance constraint using a constant range of 0 and mainCharNode as toNode:, and a positionY constraint using the midY-value of the playable screen. However it seems like the distance constraints "overpowers" the positionY constraint and the cameraNode still follows mainCharNode's x AND y values.